# Import alt text in set_post_thumbnail

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails

I am using `set_post_thumbnail` in order to programmatically attach an image to my posts.

I was wondering how to set a different alt text for this image, for every post, meaning that the same image might appear in 2 or more posts, with a different alt text.

Answer (score 1):

Got it - **update_post_meta** has to be used for **_wp_attachment_image_alt**

Comment: This will change the alt text for all posts that use that image as its thumbnail, which is not what you wanted, based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a global `alt` (meta) value associated with an attachment(viewable when managed via "media" in the admin) that's stored in the post meta table, but on a post by post basis, the alt value you set when you use that piece of media into a post is stored more literally as a portion post content HTML.

The issue i think is that WordPress doesn't respect the global(main) attachment alt value and will update the attachment meta when you insert it into a post and set the alt text, whilst the specific post alt text (post content html) for that attachment will be whatever you set it to at the time it was inserted.

By calling `update_post_meta` on `_wp_attachment_image_alt` all you'll likely to achieve is a short term fix for setting what the current alt value is, it will likely change the next time you insert it and set a differing alt value.